# connect to vpn in ubuntu 20.04 problem

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, connection

**I have VPS windows server that have VPN enabled on.

I'm already connected to that VPN with android phone and windows10.

but i want to connect to that with Ubuntu 20.04 and get "connection failed".**

is there problem with new Ubuntu?
should i change connection configuration?

> I'm connected to that VPN with other platform but can't connect with Ubuntu.

Comment: Really need more info. Which VPN do you use? What technology? What are your settings. Can your Ubuntu PC reach IP of that VPS. Etc.

Comment: it's the PPTP vpn that run in windows server , yes i can ping my server address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure PPTP please see this guide:
https://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=54

Make sure that your username and password are correctly entered, and that encryption algorithms are selected correctly. These have to exactly match settings that are on your Windows Server.

If that doesn't help, please provide (redacted) syslog file output using command below

`tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog`

Comment: i saw that link but i missed one of check box on, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just checking the log helped me a lot !!